# Print Unicode Characters to POS printer

Tags: c#, escpos, posprinter

I'm trying to print my language characters to a POS printer. The Printer prints well but the result's so bad. This is what I tried:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(ms))
                {
                    bw.Write(AsciiControlChars.Escape);
                    bw.Write('@');

                    //ESCCMD.RenderBitmap(bw, logo);
                    bw.Write("Đây là Tiếng Việt");

                    bw.Write(AsciiControlChars.Escape);
                    bw.Write('d');
                    bw.Write((byte)3);

                    // Feed 3 vertical motion units and cut the paper with a 1 point uncut
                    bw.Write(AsciiControlChars.GroupSeparator);
                    bw.Write(AsciiControlChars.V);
                    bw.Write((byte)66);
                    bw.Write((byte)3);
                    bw.Flush();

                    RawPrinterHelper.SendToSerialPort(ms.ToArray(), txtPortTest.Text, Convert.ToInt32(cbbBaudRate.SelectedValue));
                }
```

So how can I print my language characters using ESC/POS command? 
Thanks so much!

Comment: What do you mean the result is bad? Is it that the characters are not properly written? Then please make sure that font you're using supports proper characters.

Comment: Yes @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan! The characters are not properly written and there is no way to define a font-family in ESC/POS command also. I send the string as raw data to printer.

Comment: Are you sure the string encoding is right? try to convert it to string Encoding.Unicode

Comment: Yes @HusseinZawawi. I tried to convert to Encoding.Unicode and Encoding.UTF8 already. Both of those do not take effect

Comment: @HICURIN, did you managed to solve this problem? Would you be kindly to share the solution?

Comment: @Sam Yes. I managed to solve the problem 2 weeks after I posted the question. You can either try to import languages to your printer(usually doesn’t work :)) or write your own encoding and decoding classes in your language. I did wrote my own encoding and decoding classes in vietnamese. Happy coding!

Comment: @HICURIN Well done!!! And thank you for replying. Would you mind to share your code with me? I am having problem at Vietnamese (here is my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715099/c-sharp-esc-pos-print-vietnamese). Would really appreciate if you could help. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Before printing international characters you need to check if your specific model supports the corresponding codepage and then set it with the `ESC t` command. The list of supported code pages for EPSON printers and the command syntax info is available here: https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=32 (registration required)

For example, in order to print Greek (ISO-8859-7) text, you need to do something like this:

```cs
private void PrintGreekIsoText(BinaryWriter bw, string text)
{
    // ESC t 15
    bw.Write("\x1bt\x15");
    // Convert the text to the appropriate encoding
    var isoEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(28597);
    var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);
    byte[] output = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, isoEncoding, bytes);
    bw.Write(output);
}
```